# Calculate IP Between IP range PHP

Tags: php, ip, range

How do i calculate between  Ip Addresses.
for Example:

```
$ip_low_range = '91.0.0.0';
$ip_max_range = '91.23.255.255';
$user_ip  = '91.1.0.0';
in_range($user_ip , $ip_low_range , $ip_max_range,);
```

in_range() - is the function that i'm looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? We'll gladly help you, if you show us your efforts thus far! Even if the code isn't working, better show that than nothing.

Comment: How do you think this can be done? When **you** (the human) want to ensure that `91.1.0.0` is in the range `91.0.0.0 - 91.23.255.255`, how do you check that?

Comment: i'm new at SOF .. do my best to add my Attempts to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ip2long:

```
$ip_low_range = ip2long('91.0.0.0');
$ip_max_range = ip2long('91.23.255.255');
$user_ip  = ip2long('91.1.0.0');
if ($user_ip >= $ip_low_range && $user_ip <= $ip_max_range) {
    echo "in range";
}
```